# How can I get the child element value using jquery looping?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I want to get the child element dynamically. I am looping through the div tag to get the values. But its not working.

```
<div class="pg">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-3">
      <div class="fg">
        <input type="text" xl="12" value="a">
      </div>
      <div class="fg">
        <input type="text" xl="34" value="b">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The javascript function for fetching the value dynamically

This code is working if row and col div are not there. But when they are included its not working at all. Anyone can please help me with this issue!

```
$(".pg").each(function(){
   $(this).children(".fg").each(function() {
       console.log($(this).attr('xl'));
   });  
});
```

Comment: `xl` is not a valid attribute. This should be a `data-*` attribute -> `data-xl="..."`

Comment: After doing what @Andreas said, then you can use `$('input[data-xl]')` to select the inputs

Comment: But when an looping after implementating the grid. I am not able to get the values.

Comment: @lnx consider updating the code in the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First using [children()](http://api.jquery.com/children/), will return only direct children , not deep search ,

Second , use `data-xl` instead of `xl` ,more information [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/data-*) about data attribute

also , the loop is accessing the parent div of input , so use `".fg input"` instead

for searching use [find()](https://api.jquery.com/find/) , then change selector to access directly your input , `.find(".fg input")`

See below working snippet :

```js
$(".pg").each(function() {
  $(this).find(".fg input").each(function() {
    console.log($(this).val() ,"=", $(this).data('xl'));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="pg">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-3">
      <div class="fg">
        <input type="text" data-xl="12" value="a">
      </div>
      <div class="fg">
        <input type="text" data-xl="34" value="b">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="pg">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-3">
      <div class="fg">
        <input type="text" data-xl="15" value="c">
      </div>
      <div class="fg">
        <input type="text" data-xl="84" value="d">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Tq for the help. All my doubts as well as the explanation helped me to resolve the issue.. also @Andreas and evolutionxbox for helping me out.